# Text crossing the margin in amsbook

Tags: amsbook

I am currently using the amsbook class to write my thesis. It happens quite regularly that some text lines cross the margin of the document. So far, I have no clue why and in which cases that happens (e.g., it does not only happen in math environments). Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Here is some minimal example from my thesis, where this happens. I have included the packages that I use, but the same problem occurs if I do not use any of them.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,urlcolor=grey,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}
    \begin{Def}[Polynomial Hubbard Trees]
        Let $p$ be a post-critically finite polynomial. The \emph{Hubbard Tree} of $p$ is the unique finite embedded tree $H\subset\mathbb{C}$ for which the following conditions are satisfied:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $\Omega^+(C(p))\subset H$ and all endpoints of $H$ are contained in $\Omega^+(C(p))$. (\textbf{Minimality})
            \item The embedded tree $H$ is forward invariant, i.e., $p(H)\subset H$. (\textbf{Invariance})
            \item For every pair of points $z,w\in H$, the in-tree connection $[z,w]_H$ is a regulated arc. (\textbf{Normalization})
        \end{itemize}
    \end{Def}
\end{document}
```

[image: The compiled file Looks like this. As you can see, the margin is not respected.]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! with given information is almost impossible to help you ... do you use `babel` package? maybe adding `microtype` package can help you. for more you need to show (short as possible) example of your document which show your problem.

Comment: Does the issue arise mainly, or exclusively, with long words? Did you maybe suppres hyphenation?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have just edited my post. Including the microtype package does not change anything...

Comment: try `({\bfseries Minimality})` (instead of `(\textbf{Minimality})` ).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i wonder, why it make difference (enable hyphenation, meanwhile `\textbf{...}` in this particular case not). this is over my knowledge of LateX :-(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i don't know. its look like that (automatic) hyphenation in `textbf{...}` is blocked. if this is true, than this i would consider as bug.

Comment: @Zarko replacing `(\textbf{Minimality})` by `({\bfseries Minimality})` worked, thank you! I am still wondering, though, what the underlying problem is… I guess if the Editor does not know how to syllabify a word, then it might cross the margin? Also, the same happens in math mode `$...$`. Any idea how to deal with the problem when it occurs in math mode?

Comment: @saveturn, in math mode depending of the case. in normal circumstances in-line expressions with more than one word should be break between lines, but not hyphenate.

Comment: I'd solve it in another way: `\item (\textbf{Minimality}) ...`, which would give more prominence to the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that `\textbf{...}` in *combination with left parent before it* (see @egreg comment below; thank you very mach Gregorio!) block automatic hyphenation of the text inside it. it is not connected with `amsbook` document class, but also happen for example at use of `article`. so, to my opinion, this is bug ...

you have two possibilities to resolve your problem:

- manually insert hyphenation points as suggested in [Red-Cloud answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490102/text-crossing-the-margin-in-amsbook/490107#490107)
- instead `(\textbf{...})` use `({\bfseries ...})` as i suggested in my comment below question

some off-topic remarks:

- the `hyperref` package should be loaded last (in rare exception as is `cleveref`)
- `mathtolls` load `amsmath` (and improve it), so you not need load again
- `amssymb` load `amsfonts`, so you not need to load again
- `utf8` coding is included in recent (standard) document class version, so you can omit it in preamble

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb, amsthm}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \usepackage{accents}
  \usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \usepackage{todonotes}
  \usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,
              colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,urlcolor=grey,
              breaklinks]{hyperref}

  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{Def}{Definition}[section]

  \begin{document}
      \begin{Def}[Polynomial Hubbard Trees]
          Let $p$ be a post-critically finite polynomial. The \emph{Hubbard Tree} of $p$ is the unique finite embedded tree $H\subset\mathbb{C}$ for which the following conditions are satisfied:
          \begin{itemize}
              \item $\Omega^+(C(p))\subset H$ and all endpoints of $H$ are contained in $\Omega^+(C(p))$. ({\bfseries Minimality})
              \item The embedded tree $H$ is forward invariant, i.e., $p(H)\subset H$. (\textbf{Invariance})
              \item For every pair of points $z,w\in H$, the in-tree connection $[z,w]_H$ is a regulated arc. (\textbf{Normalization})
          \end{itemize}
      \end{Def}
  \end{document}
  ```

result:

[image]

Comment: It's the combination “left parenthesis followed by `\textbf`” that blocks hyphenation, not just `\textbf`.

Comment: @egreg, it might be. so far i didn't tested. and yeas, you are right. I will correct answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\textbf{Mini\-mality}`.

But it is a bit curious, because there are alread the hyphenation points 
`Min-i-mal-ity`

Comment: oh sorry I missed this, I'll delete mine which is the same,